# How to convert NSString value @"3.45" into float?

Tags: objective-c

How to convert NSString value @"3.45" into float. 3.45

```
float fCost = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"3.45"]floatValue] ;
```

Answer (score 57):

```
NSString *val = @"3.45";
float fCost = [val floatValue];
```

Comment: how do i convert @"3.4.5" to float, basically i need to compare floats with multiple points like 1.1.2>1.1.1

Answer (score 9):

```
float number = [string floatValue];
```

Answer (score 4):

NSString's: `- (float)floatValue;`

For example:

```
NSString *str = @"3.45";
float f = [str floatValue];
```

Answer (score 4):

Reading your comment to Marek's answer it looks like your string actually = `@"$3.45"`

To convert that to a float use:

```
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
formatter.currencyCode = @"USD";

float value = [[formatter numberFromString: @"$3.45"] floatValue];
```